# How to configure apache to proxy requests

Tags: apache, xmpp, mod-proxy

I want to add a javascript based chat system to my web app. I have read in many places that apache needs to forward(proxy) the requests to the xmpp chat server.
From what I have understood , I either need to add proxying support to apache server
OR use the jabberHTTPbind servelet.

I am trying the first thing. Add proxy support to apache. Now within Eclipse I am using Tomcat 7.0. I think this Tomcat comes with its own web server and is not using Apache. Is that true ?I am using Tomcat from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi and added server in Eclipse by providing its extracted path.

I am not able to find any apache related folder structure eg(/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) within my Tomcat extracted directory.Also can't find  httpd.conf anywhere .
Should I need to download apache separately and connect my tomcat to it.

I think adding proxy support to apache is required because javascript code won't be able to connect to any URL other than the current domain. so the question again is the same , where are all these apache2.conf and httpd.conf to add mod_proxy. and where can I do the virtual host mapping.

Any help to move ahead with be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Apache HTTPD server and enable reverse proxying. Read the [doc on mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on how to do this. There are tons of resources on Stackoverflow as well; search for Apache reverse Proxy. The conf files you mention are part of the Apache HTTPD install.

> javascript code won't be able to connect to any URL other than the current domain

That is generally true unless you enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: yeah .. thanks . i have gone through this and am not able to figure out anything.Is Apache HTTPD any different from the the normal apache tomcat we download eg. http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi.

Comment: Totally different softwares. HTTPD is a web server, not a servlet container. HTTPD sits in front of your Apache Tomcat and XMPP server and dispatches requests to them. You need to make a separate install.

Comment: ok . thanks . atleast i can see the httpd.conf file. All this is getting really complicated. My Tomcat application server itself has a built-in web server. And now I am installing Apache. and a reverse proxy server infront of apache. So my Apache with the the proxy module will send some of the requests to my Tomcat application server and others to XMPP server . right ?

Comment: Your apache HTTPD server **is** the Reverse Proxy. It receives **all** requests then dispatches them to your Tomcat server and to your XMPP server. The 'dispatch' rules are the Reverse Proxy rules that you configure in the HTTPD configuration files. To make things a bit more complicated, there are different protocols available for reverse proxying (AJP, etc...). Search for HOW-TOs, this is a VERY common set-up.